# Convert string stored as binary back to string

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, binary-data, type-conversion

I have stored string as binary data in db.
I am loading this data into c# as byte[]. How do I convert it to original string there?

```
declare @QRCodeLink nvarchar(max) = 'goo.gl/JCKW'
declare @QRCodeData varbinary(max) = CONVERT(varbinary(max), @QRCodeLink)
UPDATE dbo.QRCode
SET QRCodeData = @QRCodeData
WHERE ID = @ID
```

In C# code,
`Convert.ToString(qrCodeData)` results in this `"System.Byte[]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nvarchar` value is converted to a binary value where each character is two bytes.

You can convert it already when you read it from the database:

```
select convert(nvarchar(max), QRCodeData) from dbo.QRCode ...
```

Or you can use the `UTF-16` encoding to convert the data in C#:

```
string qrCodeLink = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(qrCodeData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Encoding.GetString()

```
byte[] byteArr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello");
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArr);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: I am getting the byte[] from db. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` gives me the string with `\0` between every char.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the string encoding but assuming you are using ASCII

```
string decoded = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray);
```

Where byteArray is your data from sqlserver

If it returns garbage try UTF8 or other encodings